# How to make query system with PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, queue, exec, daemon

I have some script on my website, when logged user can put some data into form, and then, PHP script will do an `exec()` function for some time, but webpage is hold still, until that PHP script and `exec()` command will end. If user close the page - he is resolve nothing, and he need to run script again.
I want to know, if that possible, to do query mode, with existens database with users. What i want:

1. User put some data and execute script. It will put record to database with `id=1 status=running`
2. User **can close webpage** and script still running
3. Between that, another user want to put some data too, but webpage checks currently executing scripts from database, and say "I'll do it later, your queue is 1", and add an record in database `id=2 status=queue`
4. First script ends executing, return values to database and set up `id=1 status=done`
5. Then if in database exist some `queue` records, it will execute it too.
6. Users can open back website, and get data from it.

What problem that i have now. PHP function `exec()` can somehow crash, or return different data, so i need to catch it right, when it executes in background. I don't know, how to correctly do, what i want. Some of the solution is, to create a daemon on PHP, but it can be difficult to control/manage daemon, i suppose.

**What is the correct way to use, without any of libraries, from scratch? It can be some examples of this? If the daemon is the correct solution - how can i setup it and control?**

Answer (score 0):

What you defines resemble the often used CRON/Background Process/AT(on Windows). i.e.

1. Create a PHP Form which save to DB as you want.
2. Then create a new PHP Script, that read from DB. perform action, store data in dB.
3. This new script is configure to run every minute/5 minute/30 minute or once per day in cron service of your server. that run PHP Script on command line.
4. It perform operation and you can send email and db update as required.

For Exec crashing it is hard to tell the reason, there are literally 1000s of them and each has there own scope of resolution. So please post that individual as separate question with more detail. Look for your hosting environment cron and hwo to write cron scripts.

EDIT:
Writing Cron is little high level than writing Web script, in cron script you need to consider following

1. It should not output anything, no echo or print, as there is noone sitting to see it.
2. If you need output for debugging, you can, but disable in live/production otherwise it might add up to server log and bloat your server.
3. You need to make script singular depending on need, there are various way of doing it, one I prefer is to drop a lock file for cron and check if file is there don't execute cron else do it, and you need to ensure that lock file gets delete always otherwise crone get stuck.
4. Sometime error handling is problem in lock file sceanrio, in that case If I know that my crone take say 15-30 minute, I put a check that if a lock file is older than 2 hrs it auto delete. so at most my cron is stuck for 2hrs.

Comment: That was a good idea, but i barely understand how to do that thing. Do you have some examples of that thing? It can be helped. If not - do not worry

Comment: I have a personal library base code it is hard to explain here, but it is not tough, just write any simple PHP Script and run it on CLI by php <scriptname> and you realise the difference, then set that on Cpanel Cron. a simple google gives lots of example.

Comment: Another question. My first script create 1 task. My second script starts automatically after some time by cronjob. After, for example 5 minutes, cronjob try to execute second script again. But it still execute things, it can be broke at all? How can i avoid that thing?

Comment: exactly why it was hard to give example. What I did is when my cron start I drop a file say  `.cronworking` and then I put everything in `try..catch` and in finally i delete this file. I mean you have to ensure that any error that can occur delete this file. and put a check at start that if file exist the cron job script just die without doing anything. so if file is not there it execute, else it opt out .. if due to error that file is not delete your cron get stuck forever.

Comment: see new edit in answer for more details.